# POP3Store fails to authenticate, only in Tomcat7 (works fine in unit tests)

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, tomcat7

This the code, which works perfect in a unit test (connects to Gmail):

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.pop3.ssl.enable", true);
props.put("mail.pop3.host", "pop.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null)
  .getStore("pop3")
  .connect("foo@...", "password");
```

When I run the same code in Tomcat7:

```
...
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect
  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:332)
  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:196)
```

What is it about?

Well, I already configured `META-INF/javamail.providers`:

```
protocol=pop3; type=store; class=com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store;
```

And I have these Maven dependencies in `WEB-INF/lib`: `javax.mail:mail:1.4.4` and `com.sun.mail:pop3:1.4.4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not failing to authenticate, it's failing to connect.  The JavaMail FAQ has [tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).  Note also:

- you should not need to touch the javamail.providers file
- the POP3 provider is included in the javax.mail:mail artifact so you shouldn't need a separate dependency for it
- you shouldn't need to set mail.pop3.port since it's the default SSL port
- you should use Session.getInstance instead of Session.getDefaultInstance

Comment: in order to make the system truly interoperable I **have to** make explicit configuration of `javamail.providers` - what if the deployment platform doesn't have `POP3` provider? My application won't work? And I have to add dependency explicitly, for the same reason. Anyway, thanks for sharing your thoughts (I upvoted you). See my answer...

Comment: As I said, the pop3 support is included in the javax.mail:mail artifact.  Adding another dependency for it is redundant, and can sometimes cause problems since you'll have two copies of the classes.  Also, the configuration for the pop3 protocol is already included in the mail.jar file in a META-INF/javamail.default.providers file.  Are you including these dependent jars in your application war file?

Comment: You're right, the problem was with my `getDefaultInstance()` call. I switched to `getInstance()` and did what you suggested above. Works perfectly now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.pop3.ssl.enable", true);
javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(props)
  .getStore("pop3s")
  .connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, "foo@...", "password");
```

I don't know why, but in this combination it works both in a unit test and in Tomcat7 container.

Comment: In this case you're using the "pop3s" protocol so the property you're setting ("mail.pop3.ssl.enable") is ignored since it's being set for the "pop3" protocol.  And you don't need it anyway with the pop3s protocol.  You should also be able to use the connect method that doesn't require you to specify a port number.

Comment: The use of getDefaultInstance could explain the difference in behavior.  The getDefaultInstance method may be accessing an already created Session, in which case your properties are ignored.  See the javadocs for details.